# Get selected values of JSON response c#

Tags: c#, json

I am new to JSON and I need to get selected values out of a JSON response. Based on some research I have already conducted I have created a POCO as per below;

```
public class RatesResponse
{
    public class Hotel
    {
        public int hotel_id { get; set; }
        public RoomTypes room_types { get; set; }
    }

    public class RoomTypes
    {
        [JsonExtensionData]
        public Dictionary<string, object> rooms { get; set; }
    }

    public class RatesResponseObject
    {
        public List<Hotel> hotels { get; set; }
    }       
}
```

The JSON response below is an example of what I am working with;

```
{
    "hotels": [
        {
            "hotel_id": 0,
            "room_types": {
                "Superior Suite Long Stay Offer - test": {
                    "url": "https://hoteltest.cosmores.com/?CHECK_IN_DATE=2017-08-20&CHECK_OUT_DATE=2017-08-31&PERSONS=2&ROOMS=3924&CURRENCY=EUR&ref=tripads",
                    "price": 1685,
                    "fees": 0,
                    "fees_at_checkout": 0,
                    "taxes": 229,
                    "taxes_at_checkout": 0,
                    "final_price": 1914,
                    "num_rooms": 1,
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "room_amenities": [
                        "BATHROOMS",
                        "BEACH",
                        "TENNIS_COURT",
                        "SWIMMING_POOL",
                        "FITNESS_CENTER",
                        "RESTAURANT",
                        "STAIRS_ELEVATOR",
                        "BED_AND_BREAKFAST",
                        "CREDIT_CARDS_ACCEPTED"
                    ],
                    "discounts": [
                        {
                            "marketing_text": "--MANOS-OFFER--",
                            "is_percent": true,
                            "amount": 13,
                            "price": 251.838154361,
                            "fees": 0,
                            "fees_at_checkout": 0,
                            "taxes": 34.1618456391,
                            "taxes_at_checkout": 0,
                            "final_price": 286
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Superior Double Room Long Stay Offer - test": {
                    "url": "https://hoteltest.cosmores.com/?CHECK_IN_DATE=2017-08-20&CHECK_OUT_DATE=2017-08-31&PERSONS=2&ROOMS=5385&CURRENCY=EUR&ref=tripads",
                    "price": 1213,
                    "fees": 0,
                    "fees_at_checkout": 0,
                    "taxes": 165,
                    "taxes_at_checkout": 0,
                    "final_price": 1378,
                    "num_rooms": 1,
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "room_amenities": [
                        "BEACH",
                        "TENNIS_COURT",
                        "SWIMMING_POOL",
                        "FITNESS_CENTER",
                        "RESTAURANT",
                        "STAIRS_ELEVATOR",
                        "BED_AND_BREAKFAST",
                        "CREDIT_CARDS_ACCEPTED"
                    ],
                    "discounts": [
                        {
                            "marketing_text": "--MANOS-OFFER--",
                            "is_percent": true,
                            "amount": 13,
                            "price": 181.32347114,
                            "fees": 0,
                            "fees_at_checkout": 0,
                            "taxes": 24.5965288601,
                            "taxes_at_checkout": 0,
                            "final_price": 205.92
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Superior Double with Sea View Long Stay Offer - test": {
                    "url": "https://hoteltest.cosmores.com/?CHECK_IN_DATE=2017-08-20&CHECK_OUT_DATE=2017-08-31&PERSONS=2&ROOMS=5386&CURRENCY=EUR&ref=tripads",
                    "price": 1011,
                    "fees": 0,
                    "fees_at_checkout": 0,
                    "taxes": 137,
                    "taxes_at_checkout": 0,
                    "final_price": 1148,
                    "num_rooms": 1,
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "room_amenities": [
                        "BEACH",
                        "TENNIS_COURT",
                        "SWIMMING_POOL",
                        "FITNESS_CENTER",
                        "RESTAURANT",
                        "STAIRS_ELEVATOR",
                        "BED_AND_BREAKFAST",
                        "CREDIT_CARDS_ACCEPTED"
                    ],
                    "discounts": [
                        {
                            "marketing_text": "--MANOS-OFFER--",
                            "is_percent": true,
                            "amount": 13,
                            "price": 151.102892617,
                            "fees": 0,
                            "fees_at_checkout": 0,
                            "taxes": 20.4971073834,
                            "taxes_at_checkout": 0,
                            "final_price": 171.6
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The fields I need to get are;

- hotel_id
- the name of the room (i.e. Superior Suite Long Stay Offer - test)
- final_price
- num_rooms

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been looking at this for 2 days now!

Comment: Are you talking about in javascript?

Comment: @Steve, no i'm not using javascript.

Comment: @Dave, In you JSON "Superior Suite Long Stay Offer - test" is property name an I think it could be a problem to have object property with spaces in C#, Is it possible to change it to: `"room_types": {
                "typeName": "Superior Suite Long Stay Offer - test",
                    "url": "https://hoteltest.cosmores.com/?CHECK_IN_DATE=2017-08-20&CHECK_OUT_DATE=2017-08-31&PERSONS=2&ROOMS=3924&CURRENCY=EUR&ref=tripads",
                    "price": 1685,`? I see that you are trying to parse it to Dictionaty, but if you would change JSON, it would be much simpler to get necessary fields

Comment: @ViktorOleksyshyn no I cannot change it as it is coming from a supplier, so I am having to use what they provide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Newtonsoft.Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm).
Here example without exceptions handling:

```
var str = "PUT_YOUR_JSON_HERE";
        var hotelData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RatesResponseObject>(str);
        foreach (var hotel in hotelData.hotels)
        {
            var id = hotel.hotel_id;
            var rooms = hotel.room_types.ToList();
                foreach (var room in rooms)
            {
                var roomName = ((JProperty)(room)).Name;
                var roomDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RoomDetails>(room.First.ToString());

                var finalPrice = roomDetails.final_price;
                var num_rooms = roomDetails.num_rooms;
            }

        }
```

And classes:

```
    public class Hotel
{
    public int hotel_id { get; set; }
    public JToken room_types { get; set; }
}

public class RatesResponseObject
{
    public List<Hotel> hotels { get; set; }
}

public class RoomDetails
{
    public int final_price { get; set; }
    public int num_rooms { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for that, it works perfectly! Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, but you need to adjust your class structure a little bit.  In particular, you need to define a `RoomType` class, and then change the `room_types` property in your `Hotel` class to be a `Dictionary<string, RoomType>`.  You can then delete the `RoomTypes` (plural) class.  If you want to capture the discount information, you'll also need to define a `Discount` class.  Here is what the final structure should look like:

```
public class RatesResponseObject
{
    public List<Hotel> hotels { get; set; }
}

public class Hotel
{
    public int hotel_id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, RoomType> room_types { get; set; }
}

public class RoomType
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public decimal fees { get; set; }
    public decimal fees_at_checkout { get; set; }
    public decimal taxes { get; set; }
    public decimal taxes_at_checkout { get; set; }
    public decimal final_price { get; set; }
    public int num_rooms { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public List<string> room_amenities { get; set; }
    public List<Discount> discounts { get; set; }
}

public class Discount
{
    public string marketing_text { get; set; }
    public bool is_percent { get; set; }
    public decimal amount { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public decimal fees { get; set; }
    public decimal fees_at_checkout { get; set; }
    public decimal taxes { get; set; }
    public decimal taxes_at_checkout { get; set; }
    public decimal final_price { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming you are using [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), you can then deserialize and extract the data you want like this:

```
var rro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RatesResponseObject>(json);

foreach (Hotel hotel in rro.hotels)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hotel ID: " + hotel.hotel_id);
    Console.WriteLine();

    foreach (var kvp in hotel.room_types)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Room Type: " + kvp.Key);
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Rooms: " + kvp.Value.num_rooms);
        Console.WriteLine("Final Price: " + kvp.Value.final_price);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wpRUzL

Comment: Thanks @BrianRogers

Comment: No problem; glad to help.

Comment: I prefer this solution because the proposed class structures are more strongly typed and probably closer to the original data structure that generated the json response. Reaching for lower level json parsing stream artefacts feels like a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Newtonsoft's `JObject`. Works perfectly for JSON.

Example usage for your case would be something like:

```
JObject myJson = JObject.Parse(jsonFromYourExample);
//now to access whatever you need, you simply do
foreach(var o in myJson["hotels"])
{
    Debug.WriteLine(o["hotel_id"]);
    // and so on depending on what level you are in
}
```

This should get you started, in working with JSON. You can read more about JObject [Here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will give it a try.